# Has anyone ever used their paper copy of their ID to get their Greyhound ticket?

Tags: driving-licenses, identity-cards, greyhound

For identification, I have a paper copy of my DMV ID (Department of Motor Vehicles). I want to take a Greyhound bus to go see my dad in California, who is sick in the hospital. Will Greyhound accept a paper copy?

Comment: when you say a "paper copy" do you mean a piece of paper that was issued to you, or a photocopy of whatever you were issued?